# Make CAGradientLayer fill the entire CAShapeLayer

Tags: swift, uikit, quartz-core

I try to add an `CAGradientLayer` on top of a `CAShapeLayer`, but I can't get the full frame of the `ShapeLayer` without messing up the position of the `GradientLayer`, so the edges seems clipped. See photos below.

With `GradientLayer`:

[image]

Without `GradientLayer`:

[image]

This is the code:

```
class CircularProgressBarView: UIView {

// MARK: - Properties
var progressLayer = CAShapeLayer()
private var startPoint = CGFloat(-Double.pi / 2)
private var endPoint = CGFloat(3 * Double.pi / 2)
private var currentValue: Float = 0
var gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
}

required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: coder)
}

override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    createCircularPath()
    createGradientPath()
}

func createCircularPath() {
    let circularPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: frame.size.width / 2.0, y: frame.size.height / 2.0), radius: frame.size.width / 2, startAngle: startPoint, endAngle: endPoint, clockwise: true)
    
    progressLayer.path = circularPath.cgPath
    progressLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    progressLayer.lineCap = .round
    progressLayer.lineWidth = 8
    progressLayer.strokeEnd = 0
    progressLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
    
    layer.addSublayer(progressLayer)
}

func createGradientPath() {
    gradientLayer.type = CAGradientLayerType.conic
    gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
    gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0)

    gradientLayer.colors = [UIColor.yellow.cgColor, UIColor.red.cgColor]
    gradientLayer.frame = self.bounds
    gradientLayer.mask = progressLayer
    
    layer.addSublayer(gradientLayer)
}

}
```

Comment: It's hard to tell what's going on since you don't show how these functions are used or the view that implements them. It looks like the shape layer is drawn into your view's bounds/frame. What draws the purple background then?

Comment: @DuncanC I just edited the question with the full code

Comment: Did you see my answer? I think it will likely fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

At a guess, you need to inset your gradient layer's frame by your line width. So use`self.bounds.insetBy(dx: lineWidth, dy: lineWidth)` as your gradient view's frame.

That should add lineWidth/2 space on all 4 edges of your gradient layer.

### Edit:

Sorry, you need to inset your Circular path by lineWidth. Try editing it like this:

```
func createCircularPath() {
    let rect = bounds.insetBy(dx: lineWidth/2, dy: lineWidth/2)
    let circularPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: rect.midX, y: rect.midY), radius: rect.size.width / 2, startAngle: startPoint, endAngle: endPoint, clockwise: true)
    
    progressLayer.path = circularPath.cgPath
    progressLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    progressLayer.lineCap = .round
    progressLayer.lineWidth = lineWidth
    progressLayer.strokeEnd = Double.pi * 2
    progressLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
    
    layer.addSublayer(progressLayer)
}
```

(Where I added an instance var `var lineWidth = 8.0`)

That produces this image on my simulator. (I made the parent view controller's view cyan so you can see what's going on with the `CircularProgressBarView`.)

[image]